# How can i access my filtered array from controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, filter, controller

I have this expression in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in (filtered = (friendsData | matchnames:search.pattern)) | myLimitTo : 9 : pageIndex * 9"" >
```

I do the filtered so i can show something like this

```
{{filtered.length}}
```

in the view which works great, but how can i access this param in the controller so i do stuff with it?

Comment: this one shows me undefined

Comment: @totothegreat try this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/AFT7ymvNiioCg4bH4B3j?p=info  let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: If you didn't pre-define the filtered variable in your controller, it's created in ng-repeat's own scope. If you declare filtered like `$scope.filtered = [];` in your controller, i think it should work..

Comment: @Rebornix He wants to access filtered, not the 'friend'  in his example, or 'person' in your plnkr.

Comment: That plunker did it, i should have used the "this" and apply the changes on it, thx man!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't access `$scope.filtered` because `ng-repeat` creates a new scope and sets `filtered` to it.

Technically you can create `$scope.viewData = {}` in your controller and use the following code in the template:

```
<div ng-repeat="friend in (viewData.filtered = (friendsData | matchnames:search.pattern)) | myLimitTo : 9 : pageIndex * 9"" >
```

There are some other possible ways to do the similar thing: eg if you use `controllerAs` you could set filtered array to it.

But in general all these tricks are not very good practice because you want to pass variable implicitly to controller and your angular expression looks quite complex.